# Logstash custom log parsing

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

Need your help in custom log parsing through logstash

Here is the log format that I am trying to parse through logstash

```
2015-11-01 07:55:18,952 [abc.xyz.com] - /Enter, G, _null, 2702, 2, 2, 2, 2, PageTotal_1449647718950_1449647718952_2_App_e9c00521-eeec-4d47-bf5b-b842ec14a4ff_178.255.153.2___, , , NEW,
```

And my logstash conf file looks like below

```
input {
  file {
    path => [ "/tmp/access.log" ]
  }
}

filter{
    grok {
       match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{GREEDYDATA:message}" }
   }
   date {
    match => ["timestamp","yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSSS"]
  }
}
```

For some reason running the logstash command passing the conf file doesnt parse the logs, not sure whats wrong with the config. Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
bin/logstash -f conf/access_log.conf
Settings: Default filter workers: 6
Logstash startup completed
```

Comment: What does "doesn't parse" mean?  You don't get a 'timestamp' field?  Your 'message' field appears unchanged?  You get a grokparseerror?  Your @timestamp isn't set correctly?

Comment: You are right, i didnt get the timestamp field. I expect to see 2015-11-01 07:55:18,952 in the \@timestamp field and rest of the logs in the \@message field

Comment: There's a difference between 'timestamp' and '@timestamp'.  Can you add a stdout{} output and post what that looks like?

Answer (score 1):

I have checked your Grok Match filter and is fine with:
[Grok Debugger](https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/)

You don't have to use the date matcher because the grok matcher already correctly match the TIMESTAMP_ISO8601 timestamp.

I think your problem is with "since_db" file. 
Here is the documentation: 
[since_db](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#plugins-inputs-file-sincedb_path)

In few words, logstash remember if a file is already read and doesn't read it anymore. Logstash remember if one file was already read because write it in the since Database. 
If you would like to test your filter reading always the same file, you could try:

```
    input {
      file {
        path => [ "/tmp/access.log" ]
        sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
      }
    }
```

Regards